# ES6 import/export not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs, es6-modules

I'm not sure if its react-native related but those are my versions:

`"react-native": "0.46.4",
"babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",`

```
// src/utils/a.js
export default 'a file works!'

// src/utils/b.js
export default 'b file works!'

// src/utils/index.js
import a from './a'
import b from './b'

export { a, b }
```

And basically when I try to:

```
import * as utils from 'src/utils'
// or
import { a, b } from 'src/utils'
```

It returns undefined "a" and "b" properties, like

```
utils = { a: undefined, b: undefined }
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, my guess is those `a/b.js` files are not loading when they should be, one hack I did before was on a listener function, `utils.auth`, where I had to `if (auth && auth.listener)`, and that worked, because right when the app starts, listener is undefined, but then right after it becomes what it is supposed to be.

Edit:
It seems that if I try:

```
// src/utils/index.js
const a = 'a works'
const b = 'b works'

export { a, b }
```

the result is the same.

Comment: Generally when you get `undefined` for a module that clearly exports a value, it is because of a cyclic dependencies in your modules. For example if you tries to import `a` from utils while utils was still loading, it won't have exported the value yet.

Comment: Exactly, thats what I believe is happening, but what can i do about it?

Comment: The snippets of code you have shown won't cause it, so it's hard to say. Ideally you'd shuffle your code around so it doesn't have cycles.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes that was the cause, I'm not sure how I would have done it differently, but if I `import a from 'src/utils/a'` it just works as expected, it's something to do with the module cycles as you said before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help guys.
So what I found that worked was:

```
import a from 'src/utils/a'
```

As @loganfsmyth said, this happened because `utils` was still loading when I tried to load `a`. Still not sure if it's related to `react-native` module imports or something else though.

Answer (score 2):

You basically can export a file without having to import it.

Have a look at my index.js in my components folder:

```
export {Content} from './Content'
export {FilterSelect} from './FilterSelect'
export {ListItem} from './ListItem'
export {Searchbar} from './Searchbar'
export {Sidebar} from './Sidebar'
export {RequiredArgument} from './RequiredArgument'
export {Loading} from './Loading'
export {ArgumentProvided} from './ArgumentProvided'
export {OverviewBar} from './OverviewBar'
export {Home} from './Home'
export {Layout} from './Layout'
```

And this is how I import them

```
import { Content, FilterSelect, ListItem, Searchbar, Sidebar, Loading, RequiredArgument, ArgumentProvided, OverviewBar} from './components/index.js'
import Layout from './components/Layout''
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know we had to put the brackets after export.
Still doesn't work though, check my edit

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be working here :

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KsEA7P7lKOuBugEy1jd

Are you sure you have all the needed babel presets ? (ES2015, STAGE-0,..)

In addition you might try to export this way :

```
import _a from './a'
import _b from './b'

export { _a as a, _b as b }
```

Comment: Yeah I know it's supposed to be working, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't out of nowhere, it has something todo with react-native I think..
I'm using `babel-preset-react-native: 2.1.0`

Comment: My other suggestion to export the modules is not working as well?

Answer (score 1):

In your import file, you are missing './' before 'src'

```
import * as utils from './src/utils'
// or
import { a, b } from './src/utils'
```

Comment: I have a `package.json` inside `src` with: `{ "name": "src" }`

Comment: I don't think package.json file in src folder would help. If you want to configure alias, I think you should use webpack alias feature. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/